# JQuery: executive function when clicking anywhere outside of div

Tags: jquery

```
    function handler1(){
        $("#navi_touch").css("visibility","visible");
        $("#navitouchbutton").css("background","red");
        $("#navitouchbutton").one("click",handler2);
        }
    function handler2(){
        $("#navi_touch").css("visibility","hidden");
        $("#navitouchbutton").css("background","#000");
        $("#navitouchbutton").one("click",handler1);
        }
    $("#navitouchbutton").one("click", handler1);
```

Right now the only way to collapse the menu is to click #navitouchbutton. How can I collapse this menu (making #navi_touch hidden) when the user clicks anywhere outside of #navi_touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to can do it is by binding a click event on the document, then check if the element you clicked on is a child of #nav_touch.

Sample Handler:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if( $(e.target).parents('#navi_touch').length ) return;

    $("#navi_touch").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#navitouchbutton").css("background", "#000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the handler to the document object

```
function handler1() {
    $("#navi_touch").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#navitouchbutton").css("background", "red");
    $(document).one("click", handler2);
}

function handler2() {
    $("#navi_touch").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#navitouchbutton").css("background", "#000");
    $("#navitouchbutton").one("click", handler1);
}
$("#navitouchbutton").one("click", handler1);
```